# replacing regex

Tags: javascript, replace, match

I have a string, such as `hi Jim  check this  @inyekwallast:wid=834982948738924797` . I'd like to replace this with `hi Jim  check this 
 <a href="" data="wid=834982948738924797"> @inyekwallast </a>`     respectively, using JavaScript.

i know that should use replace but i do not know how use it 
Any ideas or suggestions??

Comment: `data=` is an invalid HTML5 attribute. You rather mean: `data-wid=` ?

Comment: Find some inspiration here https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=javascript+regex+at+mention+site%3Astackoverflow.com and try it yourself first.

Comment: yes you say right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var input_str = 'hi Jim  check this  @inyekwallast:wid=834982948738924797';
var output_str = input_str.replace(/(@\w+):(wid=\d+)/g,  '<a href="" data="$2"> $1 </a>');
console.log(output_str);
```

You can see in console

```
//hi Jim  check this  <a href="" data="wid=834982948738924797"> @inyekwallast </a>
```

If you replace whole document, you can use the following code...

```
 <script>
    document.body.innerHTML = do_links(document.body.innerHTML);
    function do_links(body) {
        return body.replace(/(@\w+):(wid=\d+)/g,  '<a href="" data="$2"> $1 </a>');
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: yes it is true but i have function like this                                                         
 function do_links(body){
 body.replace(/\@[a-z A-Z 0-9\_]/g , )

}      i should use this can you help me??

Comment: everything is good just the output apply between " " and  i do not want to apply my output between " ".any idea about this?????

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I understand your question exactly, but you will get the required parts with these RegEx:

```
(@\w*)
```

will match the '@something' and

```
(?!:wid=)\d{18} or (?!:wid=)\d*
```

will match the wid (first one, if there are exactly 18 digits, second one if you don't know the amount of digits). I think you can figure out the rest by yourself. Otherwise don't mind asking.

EDIT: Go with the answer by @Star_Man